# mysql query to get time difference

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.6, query

I have query like this

```
SELECT user_ID, tanggal, kode_layanan, nomor_antrian, aksi_ID,jam 
FROM `transaksi` 
WHERE tanggal = '2018-10-11' 
  AND kode_layanan = 'A' 
  AND aksi_ID BETWEEN 4 AND 9
```

and the result is like the picture below

[image]

what I want to do is do calculation time difference "jam". I know there are similar question, but i think its difference condition. so how to solve query ? thanks

Comment: Why those two rows? What is their criteria?

Comment: its just for example, not just those two rows but for further rows I want to calculation like that

Comment: Not good enough. You can't ask for a difference for two arbitrary rows that have a black box around them when it shows up on stack overflow, there must be some criteria for this. Did your last post get deleted because it wasn't specific enough?

Comment: yes and I make it again to be easier to understand, can you solve this ?

Comment: So the relation  ajsu_ID 4 and 9 row? Sequential (based on what order)? Is 4 always after 9. Do they have to be the same user_ID, tanggal etc.?

Comment: 4 always after 9 for difference nomor_antrian

Comment: `4 always after 9 for difference nomor_antrian` isn't the case for the last one in your list. "after" implies order so is the order purely `jam`? If two jams are the same what is the secondary order critiera?

Comment: sorry I mean for same nomor_antrian always start from 4 (serve) then 9 (finish) and for next nomor_antrian start again from 4 (serve) then 9 (finish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your column definition will be as shown in this query:

```
select
    user_ID,
    tanggal,
    kode_layanan,
    nomor_antrian,
    aksi_ID,
    jam,

    case aksi_ID
        when 4 then
            timediff (
                jam,
                (
                    select t2.jam
                    from transaki t2
                    where t2.aksi_ID = 9
                    and t2.nomor_antrian = 
                        (
                            select max(t3.nomor_antrian)
                            from transaki t3
                            where t3.nomor_antrian < transaki.nomor_antrian
                        )
                )
            )
        else
            null
    end as idle_time

from transaki
order by jam;
```

The logic is: "if the current row has an `aski_ID` value of '4' then find the time difference between the current row's `jam` value, and the `jam` value of the row having an `aski_ID` value of 9 and a `nomor_antrian` value that is the maximum `nomor_antrian` value less than the current row's `nomor_antrian` value".

You can see [this result working on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5P6k9qMNP8UCoGHuQe1J2G/1).

Comment: thanks for your replying, but can you give me a full code because I tried your code into my code and give me some error

Comment: I'm sorry - I had one syntax, one typographical and one logic error. I have corrected the SQL in the answer. I have also added a link at the end of the answer where you can see this running on db-fiddle (ie, here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5P6k9qMNP8UCoGHuQe1J2G/1 )